# Change column value based on another column using MYSQL Triggers

Tags: mysql

i want a trigger to be able to change the value of status=1 when balance is 0 and status=0 when the value of balance is not equal to 0 after update only ..

[image: Mysql Table]

Comment: Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve]

Comment: When do you want to fire a trigger ?
After insert ??

Comment: @priyanshu after update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE  TRIGGER `db`.`trigger_name`
 AFTER INSERT ON `table_name` FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 update table 
 set status = case when new.balance = 0 then '1' else 0 end;
```

It will check value of new balance value during INSERT and update the status.
I hope this helps.

```
CREATE  TRIGGER `db`.`trigger_name`
 AFTER UPDATE ON `table_name` FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 update table 
 set status = case when balance = 0 then '1' else 0 end;
```

Comment: see my answer, It will check whole table and update.

Answer (score 3):

Use `new` row to both access and change values before the update is actioned.

```
create trigger mytrigger
before update on mytable
for each row
set new.status = (new.balance = 0);
```

Conveniently (in MySQL), `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`.